# How do you set Azure IoT Hub "System Properties" using native MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, iot, azure-iot-hub

I'm using native MQTT with an Azure IoT Hub. The underlying issue is that once the payload is routed to a blob storage it is encoded as Base64. I believe this is due to missing the System Property "contentType=UTF-8".

I tried using the following topics with no success:

```
devices/test/messages/events/contentEncoding=UTF-8&contentType=application/json
devices/test/messages/events/contentEncoding=UTF-8
devices/test/messages/events/contentEncoding=UTF-8&contentType=applicationjson
devices/test/messages/events/.contentEncoding=UTF-8
```

This put these two items into a "Properties" nest which is independent of the "System Properties" nest (see below).

```
{"EnqueuedTimeUtc":"2019-07-31T19:24:57.4290000Z","Properties":{"contentEncoding":"UTF-8","contentType":"applicationjson"},"SystemProperties":{"connectionDeviceId":"test","connectionAuthMethod":"{\"scope\":\"device\",\"type\":\"sas\",\"issuer\":\"iothub\",\"acceptingIpFilterRule\":null}","connectionDeviceGenerationId":"000","enqueuedTime":"2019-07-31T19:24:57.4290000Z"},"Body":"msginbase64insteadofutf8"}
```

I tried formatting the message according to the "Common Format" described here also with no success: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax#message-routing-query-based-on-message-properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an example of the publisher topic and system properties*:

```
devices/test/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```

Comment: Thank you, Roman. I went through the documentation several times, but likely would not have come up with that.

Comment: I have not found proper documentation anywhere, but the list of all system property identifiers can be found in the Azure C SDK, and the mapping can be inferred: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/src/iothubtransport_mqtt_common.c#L112